# How to change which page a Custom Post Type is on depending on some kind of taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

Firstly, I apologize if any of this comes off as stupid, this is my first wordpress site.

I needed the ability for a user to create 'projects' through the dashboard. A listing of all 'projects' (much like a blog) would be shown on the 'Projects' page of this website.

I made a custom post type by adding the following code to the functions.php of my child theme:

```
function project_init() {

$labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Projects','post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Project', 'post type singular name'),
'all_items' => __('All Projects'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New Project', 'Projects'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Project'),
'new_item' => __('New Project'),
'view_item' => __('View Project'),
'search_items' => __('Search in Projects'),
'not_found' =>  __('No Projects found'),
'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Projects found in trash'),
'parent_item_colon' => ''
);



$args = array(
'label' => 'projects',
  'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-hammer',
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'excerpt',
        'trackbacks',
        'custom-fields',
        'comments',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
        'author',
        'page-attributes',)
    );
register_post_type( 'projects', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'project_init', 0 );
```

So far the CPT is working fine, and all the test projects I make are showing up on the projects page.

**The Problem:**

Now I want there to be 2 different pages. One page for 'current projects', and another page for 'completed' projects'.

'Current Projects' would be listed on the 'Projects' page.......but when the user changes something on a current project like category, or tag, or something (I'm not sure what the mechanism should be) and they change it from a 'current project' to a 'completed project', that project element would be removed from its current page, and displayed on the 'completed projects' page.

What is the best way for me to do this? I already tried adding the categories of "completed" and "current" to different projects, and then tried linking that to a menu item, or a page, but I couldn't get it to work.

I greatly appreciate any help or advice anyone can give!  Thanks!

Comment: Ya, you would want to perhaps write your own query and select projects based on a category or a tag (category may be better) and create a template file where you display these results. Look up get custom post type by category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I mean:

**Fist** create a template file. I prefix all my templates with the word template: ie: `template_projects_completed.php` To designate this as a template you need a snippet of comment text at the top of the file so Wordpress knows its a template:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Projects Template  */
?>
```

Then create a new page in the Wordpress dashboard and select your template in the template dropdown as the template to use.

Then in the newly created php file put this in it.

```
<?php
//help code
$posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'projects', // your custom post type
    'category_name'=>'your_category', // Whatever you call your category ie. completed
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date', // Purely optional - just for some ordering
    'order' => 'DESC' // Ditto
) );

 if ($posts -> have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
     <ul>
         <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
         <!-- all the other pieces you want.. ie the_author() the_title() ect.. ect..-->
     </ul>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

You of course should include your header and footer in the appropriate spots: 
get_header() and get_footer()

Comment: Yo man, I really appreciate you taking the time to write out such a well explained answer! It took me a little tweaking because of the way this theme breaks things up, but your answer was perfect! Thanks again!

Comment: Although, now I'm curious. What if instead of dividing these two categories up into two different pages, I wanted to instead display them in two different sections on the same page? Is it possible to make a custom template that displays in two different sections?

Comment: @user3835347 Sorry for the late response. Yes it is possible. You can have as many queries as you want on a page. You should use the wp_reset_query() function in between them.